# Designing a non linear scoring table for an athletic contest

Tags: algorithms

I am testing Men and Women in the standing broad jump contest.
I need to create gender-specific, non-linear scoring tables.
The terminal points are 1000 and 0.
The longer the distance jumped, the more points earned.
I want to accelerate an athlete's points as he/she gets closer to the 1000 point mark.
The broad jump will be measured in feet and inches, rounding up to the nearest inch (example: a jump of 11-feet 5.5-inches is recorded as 11-feet 6-iches).
What algo is necessary to create this table?

Comment: There are many monotonic nonlinear functions.  You need to decide what yours should look like.  Having it accelerate as you get to the 1000 point mark will mean you scale has a maximum length that it covers-the length you assign 1000 points to.  I would suggest you just  get a sheet of graph paper, label the distance along the horizontal axis, points vertical, and draw the curve you want.  Then pick off the points.

Comment: Excellent -- thank you for the suggestion